# Forcing referencing assembly

Tags: c#

Is there any way to tell compiler not to remove some of the referenced assemblies that are not used by target assembly without writing dummy code?

For example I have 2 references:

```
MyAssembly
    -> MyLoggingAbstraction
    -> MyLoggingAbstraction.NLog
```

However my assembly is using only types from `MyLoggingAbstraction` which scans current `AppDomain` for assemblies and their references and attempts to find implementation. This may sound like overcomplicating things, but I'd really want to make sure that it's enough to download package from nuget and not to write any aditional code to use that package.